# codeigniter form not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web

I am trying to create a search form in my  codeigniter site header, however everytime the form is submitted, I receive a 404 error saying the page cannot be found! I have attempted to create a link to a test page and this gave me the same error.

Please observe my code below.

view(site_header)

```
<?php echo doctype(); ?>
<html lang="en">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <head>

        <title>/title>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="search">
                <?php

                 echo form_open('search_keyword');
                 echo form_label("Stumble a search ", "searchfor");
                 echo form_input("search","search");
                 echo form_submit("getSearch","Search");
                 echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </head>
</html>
```

model (model_search)

```
<?php
class Model_search extends CI_Model {

    public function get_results($search_term){
       $query = $this->db->query('SELECT embed, title FROM videos WHERE tags LIKE '%$search_term%' order by RAND() LIMIT  1');
      return $query->result();

    }
}
?>
```

Controller (site.php) default controller

```
<?php

 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Site extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home(){ 
        $this->load->model("model_get");
        $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getRand();
        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("site_content", $data);
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }      
    public function search_keyword()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_search');
        $search_term  =  $this->input->post('search');
        $data['results'] = $this->model_search->get_results($search_term);
        $this->load->view('site_header');
        $this->load->view('search_content',$data);
        $this->load->view('site_footer');
    }
}

?>
```

Results page (search_content)

```
 <body>
     <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <div id="container">
         <div id="intro">
            <?php echo heading("Search Results",1);?>   
         </div> 
         <div id ="content">
             <p>Stumble videos related to <?php echo $search_term; ?> </p>
             <?php
             foreach ($results as $row) {
                 $title = $row->title;
                 $vid = $row->embed; 
             }
             echo heading($title, 3);
             echo $vid;
             ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

perhaps I am missing something obvious, however I think it may be to do with my .htaccess file which is posted below

(.htaccess)

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /code/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter URLs need *both* the controller name and the method.

```
form_open('site/search_keyword')
```

Comment: Even when I add the controller name as suggested, I receive the same error and the page is not found

Comment: What URL is it trying to go to?  What do you see in your URL bar?

Comment: I receive this error the requested URL /stumble/site/search_keyword was not found on this server. It is hosted on WAMP fyi

Comment: What's the URL of the search page?  Is your `base_url` config option set correctly?

Comment: base_url is set correctly as the stylesheets are being refered to. The URL of the search page is simply the index page right now as the form will appear in the header of every page. It is at localhost/stumble/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question, but did you remove the "index.php" from the $config['index_page'] variable in your config.php ?

And if you don't use any route to link 'search_keyword' to 'site/search_keyword', be sure to use the form_open('site/search_keyword') as specified previously.

Btw, here's the .htaccess I always use on my Codeigniter projects to rewrite the urls. Just add your RewriteBase on this to make it work.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I did remove index.php from the config file, I will give this new htaccess a try, thanks

Comment: new .htaccess doesnt appear to be working either. does anyone have any other suggestions?